# What is the correct notation for $\frac{du}{dx} * dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

first post on stackexchange here, so please excuse any incorrect formatting or wording, etc.

I'm currently studying intermediate integration, especially integration by parts and *u*-substitution. I am a little confused as to what the case is when writing  $du$.

For instance, I know that $\int f(g(x)) * g'(x) dx = \int f(u) du$ where u = g(x).

In regards to integration by parts, however, the formula I have learnt is $$\int u dv = uv - \int v du$$

I think this mean the same as $\int u \frac{dv}{dx} dx = uv - \int v \frac{du}{dx} dx$, but is one more correct than the other?

My teacher has told me to use the second notation as it is more "mathematical" and **doesn't involve treating the differentials as fractions**. Which is more objectively correct for use within a calculus course?

Comment: Just remember that $u\; dv$ only means $u(x)v'(x)\; dx$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first notation is not correct in my opinion and really misleading, you are right that it is meant to mean the second expression you give, but there is a lot of ambiguity here as it also appears to be the integral of $f$ w.r.t a varialbe $u$, rather than the integral of the product of $f$ with the derivative of $u$.

The way I write it is using a prime to denote differentiation:
$$
\frac{dv}{dx} := v'
$$
Then the formula becomes:

$$
\int u v' = uv - \int u' v
$$

This to me is much clearer.

As a bonus part to the answer, have you seen how to derive integration by parts? Remembering this means you can just work out the formula if you forget it. It works as follows:

Differentiating the product $uv$ with the chain rule gives,
$$
(uv)' = u'v + uv'
$$

Rearranging then gives,
$$
uv' = (uv)' - u'v
$$

Then integrating both sides,
$$
\int uv' = \int(uv)' -\int u'v = uv - \int u' v
$$
Giving us the formula.